# save xml data to CSV

Tags: java, xml, csv, parsing, xml-parsing

I have simple class to read XML file from the disc.

I don't know, how to save the result to CSV file?
Can you please help me?

```
package praser;   
public class ReadXML {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        File xmlFile = new File("C:\\test2.xml");                
        DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();            
        Document document = documentBuilder.parse(xmlFile);            
        NodeList list = document.getElementsByTagName("Developer");

        for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {

            Node node = list.item(i);                
            if(node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){                    
                Element element = (Element) node;                    
                System.out.println("Id: " + element.getAttribute("Id"));
                System.out.println("Name " + element.getElementsByTagName("Name").item(0).getTextContent());
                System.out.println("Surname " + element.getElementsByTagName("Surname").item(0).getTextContent());
                System.out.println("Age " + element.getElementsByTagName("Age").item(0).getTextContent());
            }  }}}
```

My xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Developer Id="1">
    <Name>Tom</Name>
    <Surname>Hawk</Surname>
    <Age>100</Age>

    <Name>Tom2</Name>
    <Surname>Hawk2</Surname>
    <Age>200</Age>
</Developer>
```

Comment: What do you want the CSV to look like? "Id;Name;Surname;Age" ? <- Here there is only ";" used as delimiter. CSV can use a variety of delimiters and also Value-Delimiters. So you could also want something like "Id","Name","Surname","Age" ... Also: You seem to be able to read all the information, what exactly is your trouble writing it to a line in a file?

Comment: I need to save the result(name, surname, age) with headers....I don't know how to write this to the new csv file :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code segment :

package praser;
public class ReadXML {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    File xmlFile = new File("C:\\test2.xml");                
    DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();            
    Document document = documentBuilder.parse(xmlFile);            
    NodeList list = document.getElementsByTagName("Developer");

Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("pathToFile"), "UTF-8");
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(writer);
String id, name, surname, age, line;

    for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {

        Node node = list.item(i);                
        if(node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){                    
            Element element = (Element) node;       
            id = element.getAttribute("Id");
            name = element.getElementsByTagName("Name").item(0).getTextContent();
            surname = element.getElementsByTagName("Surname").item(0).getTextContent();
            age = element.getElementsByTagName("Age").item(0).getTextContent();
            line = String.format("%s\t%s\t%s\t%s", id, name, surname, age);
            bw.write(line);
            bw.newLine();
            bw.flush();             
        }  }}}
```

Input file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Data>
<Developer Id="1">
    <Name>Tom</Name>
    <Surname>Hawk</Surname>
    <Age>100</Age>
</Developer>
<Developer Id="2">
    <Name>jessy</Name>
    <Surname>Jay</Surname>
    <Age>16</Age>
</Developer>
</Data>
```

output :

```
1   Tom Hawk    100
2   jessy   Jay 16
```

Comment: Writing directly to C:\ could be problematic regarding user rights. I also suggest using try-with-resources for the writer. And what you are writing is not CSV. It should contain one dataset per line.

Comment: I changed the out put location, but how do it that id will be in 1 col, name into 2 column, surname = 3 column etc....?

Comment: its as simple as removing line bw.newLine();

Comment: Personally, I'd use something like `String.format("%s,%s,%s,%s", id, name, surname, age);`

Comment: I did:  bw.write(String.format("%s,%s,%s,%s", element.getAttribute("Id"), element.getElementsByTagName("Name").item(0).getTextContent(), 
                       element.getElementsByTagName("Surname").item(0).getTextContent(), element.getElementsByTagName("Age").item(0).getTextContent()));

Comment: That's a good start. Add a line break at the end ( "\n" or do bw.newLine() ). You can look up what you can do with format specifiers here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

Comment: @Fildor, Modified my code. It would save IO Operations

Comment: thanks, last question: when I add into xml second <Name><Surname>.....it's not write to csv, do you knwo why? I update my code above

Comment: can't see why it isn't working in your case, may be you are using wrong input format in xml file

Comment: there must be one and only one root tag my friend. You can't add another developer if its root. To add other developer, you need another root.

Comment: ok got it, it's possible to split the result into seperate col?
id 1 col, name 2 col, surname 3 col...

Comment: they are already separated by tab, use tab as a delimiter in excel

Comment: ok, so it't not possible to save it in seperate columns? (tab delimerer is working, just checked)

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to write the content in to csv file. This solution is based on the initial XML provided in the question as below.

```
<Developer Id="1">
  <Name>Tom</Name>
  <Surname>Hawk</Surname>
  <Age>100</Age>
</Developer>
```

The code to read this xml and save it to csv can used following java code

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.*;

public class ReadXML {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    File xmlFile = new File("C:\\test2.xml");
    File outputFile = new File("Output.csv");
    DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = documentBuilder.parse(xmlFile);
    NodeList list = document.getElementsByTagName("Developer");


    BufferedWriter bw = null;
    FileWriter fw = null;
    try {
        if (!outputFile.exists()) {
            outputFile.createNewFile();
        }
        // true = append file
        fw = new FileWriter(outputFile.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
        bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

        for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {

            Node node = list.item(i);
            if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element element = (Element) node;
                System.out.println("Id: " + element.getAttribute("Id"));
                System.out.println("Name " + element.getElementsByTagName("Name").item(0).getTextContent());
                System.out.println("Surname " + element.getElementsByTagName("Surname").item(0).getTextContent());
                System.out.println("Age " + element.getElementsByTagName("Age").item(0).getTextContent());
                bw.write(element.getAttribute("Id") + ","
                        + element.getElementsByTagName("Name").item(0).getTextContent() + ","
                        + element.getElementsByTagName("Surname").item(0).getTextContent() + ","
                        + element.getElementsByTagName("Age").item(0).getTextContent() + "," + "\n");
            }
        }

    }

    catch (IOException e) {
        // catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

        try {

            if (bw != null)
                bw.close();

            if (fw != null)
                fw.close();

        } catch (IOException ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();

        }
    }

}
}
```

Output.csv will be give similar to below screen.

[image]

Comment: it's possible to split the output into columns?
id =1 col, name = 2 column, surname = 3 column, age it's 4 column

Comment: I haven't seen aligned CSV. That's what the delimiters are for. But if you absolutely want it to be aligned to columns, you could use String.format with according format specifiers for width. You would have to make sure, values don't exceed your column width, though.

Comment: Are you need to be in column or Row  ? Because if you open the csv in excel you can see each data on each column

Comment: Name is one column, Surname into second column, Age into 4th column

Comment: Check the csv output which I have added in to the answer

Comment: pelase check it as Im still geting evrythink into one column

Comment: @Coder - can you please check the your code above? I thnik you did not update it as Im still geting everything into one line

Answer (score 0):

To get the data in separate column you have to use delimiters as comma `,`.

1. If you just want data in below format without filling the data in specific colum
   Example :

```
ID;Name;Age
01;Deepak;22
```

For above result you have to use semi column `;` as delimiter.

2. If you want to put data in the columns you have to use comma `,` as delimiter.